# How to calculate the annual average share price for 25 year for individual companies using the daily closing price in R?

Tags: r

My data set looks like this: Daily closing share price is given for 25 years from 1991 to 2016 for each trading date.

```
Company Code   Company Name       Daily Trading Dates   Daily Closing Share price

43677          CENTURY ENKA LTD.  1/1/1991              3550.00
 -do-           -do-              1/2/1991              3600.00
                                   .                    3700.00
                                   .                    3800.00
                                  12/31/1991             x
                                   .                     x
                                   .                     x
                                  1/1/2016               x
                                   .                     x
                                   .                     x
                                  12/31/2016             x
```

Comment: Please 1. Fix the formatting (I just helped you with this in an edit) 2. include your question in the body of the question 3. Show what you've done thusfar to answer your question and where you got stuck 4. make sure that your data and code are in a reproducible format.

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments on my question. I am a new user of stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

i think the `SMA` function in the `TTR` package may help. here is an example:

```
library(TTR)
p1 <- c(45,68,98,97,45,12,46,98,45,65,97,48,65,95) #dummy price data
SMA(p1,4) #calculate a 4 period simple moving average 
#here is outcome 
[1]    NA    NA    NA 77.00 77.00 63.00 50.00 50.25 50.25 63.50 76.25
[12] 63.75 68.75 76.25
```

so within the SMA function, if you set the second argument to 252 -- the number of trading days in a year -- i think you will get an annual average share price for the past year for each date in your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

I would use package `lubridate`and either `tapply` or `ave`. In what follows I assume that your data is in the form of a `data.frame` named `dat`.

```
library(lubridate)

yr <- year(mdy(date))

res1 <- tapply(dat$price, yr, FUN = mean)
res2 <- ave(dat$price, yr, FUN = mean)
```

The difference between the two is that `ave` returns a vector the length of the input vector, whereas `tapply` returns a vector with as many elements as groups defined by the grouping variable(s), in this case `yr`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. Why I am getting an error something like this: Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz(x)) : 'origin' must be supplied.

Comment: To know what's going on we need data. Post the output of `dput(head(dat, 30))`, where `data` is your df.